# Meteor.js publish only to one user based on their id

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm creating a simple match making system for a game in **Meteor**, my architecture is pretty simple: I have a server side collection `waitingList` that inserts user ids while they are waiting.

When a user joins the list, it will check if there is another user on the list, if there is, it should confirm if both players are ready and then creates the game.

On plain `node.js with socket.io` this would be very simple, since each user is in it's **own room** I'd just broadcast the message to both user rooms and get them both to receive a **Are you ready?** confirmation.

I'm new to meteor, and I'm a bit lost, how could I send confirm just for the two users selected on the list and not for all the users that are currently waiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way I can think of is to just publish the collection of waiting users to each user:

```
Meteor.publish('otherWaitingUsers',()={
  return Meteor.users.find({ waiting: true, _id: { $ne: this.userId }},{ fields: { waiting: 1 }});
});
```

And then subscribe to that on the client. If there is another user waiting then you will see it on the client.

You'll still have to deal with situations when there are many people waiting and picking partners.

Comment: Actually the server will do the matchmaking by automatically selecting a user from the list, user's won't be able to pick opponents

Comment: Then you'd have to modify the above query accordingly to select the match for this player.

Comment: It also seems to me that publish the whole collection of users waiting to every user a bit unnecessary (unless meteor architecture requires that to happen). The collection could stay on server side, but only publish some message to users who would actually join a game. Do you think meteor could do that?

Comment: Yes of course, you can publish a subset of users. The query just needs to be written according to your data model. You're not so much publishing a _message_ here as a _cursor of users who are ready to play_. It's all reactive as well so as this list changes the client will automatically reflect the current state of the list.

Comment: @Michael Floyd, so I could publish a subset of users, but that would go to all users subscribed on that publish, right? Is there a way, in Meteor, to publish TO a subset of users?

Comment: You can publish a different subset of users to each user. The query on the server can be personalized using `this.userId` - the `_id` of the logged-in user who is subscribing. In the end, same thing as what you're looking for.